# adding headers in listview

Tags: android

My application showing the output in a listview like this:

```
item1
item2
imem3 
item4
```

now i want to show the items with a date header like this

```
datex
item1
datey
item2
item3
datez
item4
```

I want to categorize data under date header. How can I do this from getview? I am calling the listadapter like this:

```
 adapter=new FixtureAdapter(this, GameIdAry, DateAry, Date1Ary, TimeAry, VenuAry,
      WeekAry, TimerAry, LteamAry, LidAry, VteamAry, VidAry, LScoreAry, VScoreAry,
      LGoalAry, LBehindAry, VGoalAry, VBehindAry, StatusAry, LOddsAry, VOddsAry);
```

and the data is handling in arrayadapter

```
getview(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fixture_row_xml, parent, false);
}
```

Please help me friends

Comment: you need to google demo for "Section Header ListView"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a nice post [here](http://bartinger.at/listview-with-sectionsseparators/) of how to do a ListView with separators.

Answer (score 1):

try to use section headers in which you have to modify your Adapter and input data. Below is the link for the same.
http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/